# In the lab X vs. in the lab called X vs. in the X lab

Tags: difference

I'm not sure which sentence(s) the following ones is/are correct:

- I work in the lab X.
- I work in the lab called X.
- I work in the X lab.

X could be one word (e.g. "Haystack") or several (e.g. "Machine Learning for All").

What is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

Options 2 and 3 would work.
3 would be the best choice.
If you want to say option 2, say:

> I work in ***a*** lab called X.

Comment: Either the lab has an official name or it doesn't. Official names would put "lab" last, as in your third example. "Applied Physics Lab".  It would never be "Lab Applied Physics", although it could be "The Laboratory for Applied Physics". (note capitalization)  It would be redundant to say "the lab called X" if you cite the official name!  However, If there is no official name, your third example is the only choice, you can't say it's called by a name it doesn't have. You can only describe it generically: "I work in [a/the] chemistry lab." (note lower case)